# How to remove class in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Well I have a menu with `li` tags and it has an `a` element has a child for navigation and everything works fine , the problem is that I want to remove all the elements, which has the class `seleccionado` and add only the `li` on which I'm clicking. I tried `.remove` to remove the class. It doesn't work, so is there any other option??

The function removes first all elements with that class and after that it only adds the class to the `li`, which has been clicked.

```
clicked(event) {
   var el = document.getElementsByClassName("detectar");
   el.classList.remove("seleccionado");

   if(window.location.pathname){
       event.path[3].classList.add("seleccionado");
   }
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using traditional DOM manipulation in Angular. Look at `[ngClass]`

Comment: remove click event on child li, and it will be limited to parent li

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nm8ut?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 4):

you should avoid using javascript DOM manipulation in Angular. Check my example below. Angular is very powerfull and does not need to use traditional DOM manipulation

```
this.showMyClass = true;
clicked(event){
    this.showMyClass = false;
}
```

in Html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'myClass': showMyClass}"> </div>
```

Comment: i use the ng class but how could i restrinct only for the parent "li" , because it paints everything .
Here's a little demo :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbmfzi

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. but you are now asking different question. If you feel that this answer is helpfull please consider to upvote/ mark it as answer so that the comminity can benefit from it